# Object going out of scope / transferring ownership

Tags: c++, scope

I have an issue with creating objects, adding them to a container class, and having them go out of scope in C++.

As an example, my **main.cpp**

```
Container container;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Item item;
    container.add_item(item);
}
```

and the interface of **container.h**

```
struct Container {
    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<Item>> items;
    void add_item(Item& item); // Push back of items vector.
};
```

and **item.h**

```
struct Item {
    std::unique_ptr<AnotherThing> unrelated_thing;
};
```

The problem is later on in my main class, the *Containers* created inside the for-loop have gone out of scope. If I change add_item to pass by value, it gives me issues with the unique_ptr and copy constructor.

Is there some idiomatic way to create objects inside a scope and "transfer" them to another class?

Comment: It's to use a `std::vector` and `emplace_back(std::move(item));` into it.

Comment: `std::reference_wrapper` does not keep objects alive.

Comment: Expanding on @FrançoisAndrieux 's comment, I believe he would also exchange `std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<Item>> items;` for  `std::vector<Item> items;`.

Comment: You should not be using `reference_wrapper` in this situation. Change `items` to simply `std::vector<Item>`, and change `add_item()` to move the *content* of the input object into `items` using move semantics to transfer ownership of the `unique_ptr`

Comment: Thanks to all of you, that's very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I change add_item to pass by value, it gives me issues with the unique_ptr and copy constructor.

Your vector need to hold objects by value:

```
std::vector<Item> items;
```

then you need to move your object into vector when passed by value:

```
void Container::add_item( Item item )
{
     items.push_back( std::move( item ) );
}
```

and then you need to move your object in the loop as well:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Item item;
    container.add_item( std::move(item) );
}
```

or you can simply pass temporary:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    container.add_item( Item() );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to handle this. This is basically the exact use-case for passing xvalues. Passing by value will cause a copy of all members of item. If there are members that could have large amounts of data allocated on the heap, such as a std::vector, you will want to avoid this copy and allocation by moving your members.

The simple answer is to pass by what Scott Meyers calls a 'Universal Reference'

```
void Container::add_item( Item&& item) {
    items.push_back( std::move(item))
}
```